# how to center a webpage in CSS

Tags: css

i am i am new in CSS.. i have converted my psd file into html/css.. now i want to move my webpage page into center of the window.. i tried some code and that code align only text the background image "back.gif" remains at left.. here is my html and CSS code"

```
**HTML**

<body>
<div id="main">

      <div id="header">
     <div id="logo">
            <img src="logo.gif" />
         </div>
      </div>

     <div id="menu">
     <img src="images/menu_07.gif" />
           <div id="m">
             <ul>
               <li> <a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
               <li> <a href="pages.php">Pages</a></li>
               <li> <a href="donor.php">Donor</a></li>
               <li><a href="seeker.php">Seeker</a></li>
               <li><a href="hospitals.php">Hospitals</a></li>
               <li><a href="lifesaving.php">Life Saving Contacts</a></li>
               <li><a href="contactus.php">Feedback</a></li>
             </ul>
           </div>
     </div>

     <div id="content">
     <div id="center" align="center">
             <h3>WELCOME TO ADMIN AREA</h3>
             <p id="ajk">AJKBLOODBANK.COM</p>
         <?php
              echo "welcome!".$_SESSION['username'];
              echo "<br>";
              echo "<a href=logout.php>Logout</a>&nbsp;";
             ?>
         </div>
     </div>

     <div id="footer">
     </div>
</div>
</body>


**CSS**
body
{

    background:url(../back.gif) repeat-y;   
    padding-left:105px;
    height:900px;
    text-align: center;
    margin:auto;
    min-width: 760px;
}
div#main 
{
    width: 720px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}

#header
{
    width:787px;
    margin-top:10px;
}

#menu
{

    width:787px;    
    float:left;
    margin-top:20px;

}

#content
{
    background-color:#FFF;
    border:groove;
    width:790px;
    float:left;
    padding-top:30px;
    margin-top:30px;
}
#footer
{
        float:left;
        height:52px;
        width:790px;
}
```

Please tell me where i made mistake ..

```
the diameseion of background image "backgif" = 995x1000
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whichever element you want centered - set an explicit width and then set left/right margins to `auto`

```
#main { width:995px; margin:0 auto; }
```

...this will center the element in its parent.  If you were to center `#main`, it would be centered on the page (assuming your `body` has 100% width)

***EDIT***

Try making your background image apply to `#main` instead of `body`.  Or, center the background image using `background-position`, or shorthand:

```
body { background:url(../back.gif) repeat-y center top; }
```

Cheers

Comment: `body {
  background:url(../back.gif) repeat-y center top;
   }
#main {
 background:url(../back.gif) repeat-y;
  width:995px; 
  margin:0 auto;
   }`      this moved the background image into center.. but the main div is at left.. @Madbreaks

Comment: Take a deep breath. Why put the background image in both elements?  Put it in the body element. If `#main` is still on the left, try adding `height:100%; width:100%;` to your `body` css.

Comment: yes it works now .. i just add padding on Main div.. thnx alot :) @Madbreaks

Answer (score 4):

To center the body element, I would use something similar to this:

```
.body {
    width: 940px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Using shorthand, `margin: 0 auto;` 0 for top and bottom, auto for left and right.

Comment: @Whymarrh: Not sure I get your point. Yes, there are other ways to write it. However, your shortcut requires that I know/set the top margin as well. I was making no assumptions about the top margin.

Comment: @Jonathan.. i just checked your code.. my background image is still as left

Comment: @maham, as stated, I was showing how to center the *body* tag as a more general way to show how to center elements. You have many choices here. You can set the body width to the same width as your background image--thus, the image is centered. Or, you can use a similar syntax to center the image within the body.

Comment: @JonathanWood I was just adding it as an option to readers. The longer version is more readable imo too.